# Long to wide format from first column

Tags: r, correlation, spread, wide-format-data

I have an excel file with the headings: trait, genotype_id, BLUE, BLUE_SE, BLUP, BLUP_SE and heritability.
All columns contain numbers except the trait column. This column has the traits Fe, Zn and S. So I have like 3 sets of data underneath each other. I want these to be summarised for the genotype so I have something like
genotype_id, BLUE_Fe, BLUE_Zn, BLUE_S, BLUE_SE_Fe etc.
How do I transform this file in R so that the traits are not only one column, but that I have the characteristics for Fe, Zn and S in separate columns respectively so that I can create a correlation matrix in R afterward?

I tried

```r
data_wide <- spread(allBLUEs, trait, BLUE)
```

but this then obviously only moves the BLUEs into the same rows. I tried

```r
data_wide <- spread(allBLUEs, key = trait, value = c(BLUE, BLUE_SE, BLUP, BLUP_SE, heritability), sep = "_")
```

but the value term seems to only be able to look at one column?

my data

```r
df=tribble(~trait,~genotype_id,~BLUE,~BLUE_SE,~ BLUP,~BLUP_SE,~ heritability,
           "Fe", 3, 47.2, 2.13, 43.0, 1.76, 0.685,
           "Fe", 386, 42.5, 2.13, 39.8, 1.76, 0.685,
           "Zn", 3, 24.4, 1.74, 23.6, 1.18, 0.456,
           "S", 386, 1253, 51.3, 1269, 38.0, 0.545)
```

Comment: Can you post a sample code of the original data and a sample code of desire output?

Comment: My data looks like (headers) : 
trait , genotype_id , BLUE , BLUE_SE , BLUP , BLUP_SE , heritability

Comment: <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>

Comment: 1 Fe 3 47.2 2.13 43.0 1.76 0.685

Comment: 2 Fe 7 37.2 2.13 36.2 1.76 0.685 ...

Comment: 80 Fe 386 42.5 2.13 39.8 1.76 0.685

Comment: 81 Zn 3 24.4 1.74 23.6 1.18 0.456 ...

Comment: 240 S 386 1253. 51.3 1269. 38.0 0.545

Comment: and I would want it to look like something like: genotype_id , BLUE_Fe , BLUE_SE_Fe , ... , heritability_Fe , BLUE_Zn , and so on .. -> so only displaying each genotype once with the values. Does this help? Sorry I am new here :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it with `pivot_wider` form `tidyr`.

```r
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
df=tribble(~trait,~genotype_id,~BLUE,~BLUE_SE,~ BLUP,~BLUP_SE,~ heritability,
           "Fe", 3, 47.2, 2.13, 43.0, 1.76, 0.685,
           "Fe", 386, 42.5, 2.13, 39.8, 1.76, 0.685,
           "Zn", 3, 24.4, 1.74, 23.6, 1.18, 0.456,
           "S", 386, 1253, 51.3, 1269, 38.0, 0.545)
df %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = trait,
    values_from = BLUE:heritability
  )

#> # A tibble: 2 × 16
#>   genoty…¹ BLUE_Fe BLUE_Zn BLUE_S BLUE_…² BLUE_…³ BLUE_…⁴ BLUP_Fe BLUP_Zn BLUP_S
#>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1        3    47.2    24.4     NA    2.13    1.74    NA      43      23.6     NA
#> 2      386    42.5    NA     1253    2.13   NA       51.3    39.8    NA     1269
#> # … with 6 more variables: BLUP_SE_Fe <dbl>, BLUP_SE_Zn <dbl>, BLUP_SE_S <dbl>,
#> #   heritability_Fe <dbl>, heritability_Zn <dbl>, heritability_S <dbl>, and
#> #   abbreviated variable names ¹​genotype_id, ²​BLUE_SE_Fe, ³​BLUE_SE_Zn,
#> #   ⁴​BLUE_SE_S
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Yess this is exactly what I meant! Thank you soso much! I tried the pivot thing, but had the names and values wrong, so this is perfect and very very helpful :)